# Cannot use Azure Communication Service from kubernetes pod

Tags: azure, kubernetes, dns, azure-communication-services

I have an api in ASP.NET Core that uses Azure SDK to send emails. The code is :

```
var connectionString = "<>";  
var _client = new EmailClient(connectionString);
// Create the email content
var emailContent = new EmailContent("Hello") { Html = "This is body" };

// Create the recipient list    
var emailRecipients = new EmailRecipients(new List<EmailAddress> { new("someaddress@gmail.com") });

// Create the EmailMessage
var emailMessage = new EmailMessage(
    "somesender@2454566-027c-491a-a783-ssasd234442.azurecomm.net",
    emailRecipients, emailContent);

try
{
    await _client.SendAsync(WaitUntil.Started, emailMessage);

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

I am sure that the parameters are correct and that it is working in none Kubernetes environment. The problem is when I start app from Kubernetes it is showing me this error on ArgoCD:

```
 System.AggregateException: Retry failed after 4 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry or by configuring a custom retry policy in ClientOptions.RetryPolicy. (Resource temporarily unavailable (srpcommunicationservice.asiapacific.communication.azure.com:443)) (Resource temporarily unavailable (srpcommunicationservice.asiapacific.communication.azure.com:443)) (Resource temporarily unavailable (srpcommunicationservice.asiapacific.communication.azure.com:443)) (Resource temporarily unavailable (srpcommunicationservice.asiapacific.communication.azure.com:443))
       ---> Azure.RequestFailedException: Resource temporarily unavailable (srpcommunicationservice.asiapacific.communication.azure.com:443)
       ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Resource temporarily unavailable (srpcommunicationservice.asiapacific.communication.azure.com:443)
       ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11): Resource temporarily unavailable
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|285_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, Boolean async)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, Boolean async)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineTransportPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
         at Azure.Communication.Pipeline.HMACAuthenticationPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RedirectPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
         at Azure.Communication.Email.EmailRestClient.SendAsync(EmailMessage message, Nullable`1 operationId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Azure.Communication.Email.EmailClient.SendEmailInternalAsync(WaitUntil wait, EmailMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Azure.Communication.Email.EmailClient.SendAsync(WaitUntil wait, EmailMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at MRA.Configurations.Azure.EmailService.EmailService.SendEmailAsync(IEnumerable`1 receives, String body, String subject)
       ---> (Inner Exception #1) Azure.RequestFailedException: Resource temporarily unavailable (srpcommunicationservice.asiapacific.communication.azure.com:443)
       ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Resource temporarily unavailable (srpcommunicationservice.asiapacific.communication.azure.com:443)
       ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11): Resource temporarily unavailable
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|285_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, Boolean async)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, Boolean async)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineTransportPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
         at Azure.Communication.Pipeline.HMACAuthenticationPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RedirectPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)<---
       ---> (Inner Exception #2) Azure.RequestFailedException: Resource temporarily unavailable (srpcommunicationservice.asiapacific.communication.azure.com:443)
       ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Resource temporarily unavailable (srpcommunicationservice.asiapacific.communication.azure.com:443)
       ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11): Resource temporarily unavailable
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|285_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, Boolean async)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, Boolean async)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineTransportPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
         at Azure.Communication.Pipeline.HMACAuthenticationPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RedirectPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)<---
       ---> (Inner Exception #3) Azure.RequestFailedException: Resource temporarily unavailable (srpcommunicationservice.asiapacific.communication.azure.com:443)
       ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Resource temporarily unavailable (srpcommunicationservice.asiapacific.communication.azure.com:443)
       ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11): Resource temporarily unavailable
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|285_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, Boolean async)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, Boolean async)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineTransportPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
         at Azure.Communication.Pipeline.HMACAuthenticationPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RedirectPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)<---
```

I researched a lot, and it looks like some of the azure services have this problem (Key Vault for example). I did some troubleshooting, installed ping on my cluster, connected to the pod with exec and ping azure service endpoing. It looks like sometimes it is working and sometimes giving me this error:

```
ping: myservice.asiapacific.communication.azure.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Ping is working when I use IP address of azure endpoint.

Is there any idea to resolve this issue?

I am using an on-premise host and docker desktop, my machines OS is Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was happening almost with all azure services. After diagnosing the problem, I found some logs from dns pod, like:

```
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 eastasia-0.in.applicationinsights.azure.com. A: dns: buffer size too small
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 eastasia-0.in.applicationinsights.azure.com. A: dns: buffer size too small
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 eastasia-0.in.applicationinsights.azure.com. AAAA: dns: overflow unpacking uint32
```

Then after some research I changed dns config map with `kubectl edit configmap coredns -n kube-system`. Before it was

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health {
           lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
           pods insecure
           fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
           ttl 30
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf {
           max_concurrent 1000
        }
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2024-01-03T06:10:31Z"
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "265"
  uid: d7617a24-de5a-4825-922f-dcc4a62f3ee2
```

Then I changed this line (Google dns): `forward . 8.8.8.8`

Now, everything is working. It seems something was wrong with my coreDns configuration